# Javascript - clearing everything inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div:

```
<div id="socialUserList">
//some content here, htmlTags, text, etc.
</div>
```

Now, I want everything inside of that div to be wiped out. I am trying this:

```
$("#socialUserList").innerHTML = '';
```

But for some reason it doesn't want to work. Why?

Comment: jQuery objects does'nt have a innerHTML method, only native JS objects do!

Comment: @adeneo Yet; you can combine them, like this: `var testInner = $('#testInner'); console.log(testInner[0].innerHTML);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal JavaScript method:

```
document.getElementById('socialUserList').innerHTML = '';
```

In jQuery:

```
$('#socialUserList').html('');
```

---

*Pure JavaScript and jQuery go hand in hand, like so:*

From pure JavaScript to jQuery:

```
var socialUserList = document.getElementById('socialUserList');
console.log($(socialUserList).html());
```

From jQuery to pure JavaScript:

```
var socialUserList = $('#socialUserList');
console.log(socialUserList[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
jQuery('#socialUserList').empty();
```

Note: You may have also tried this:

```
jQuery('@socialUserList')[0].innerHTML = '';
```

Using the `[0]` will access the DOM object of the first matching element.